# On $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is a nonempty set. If $\mathcal{E}\subseteq 2^{X}$ (the power set of $X$), the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal{E}$ is called  the $\sigma$-algebra *generated by* $\mathcal{E}$, and is denoted by $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$. I am trying to prove the following exercise:

> If $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$,
>   then $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ is the union of the $\sigma$-algebras generated by
>   $\mathcal{F}$ as $\mathcal{F}$ ranges over all countable subsets of
>   $\mathcal{E}$. (Hint: Show that the latter object is a
>   $\sigma$-algebra)

My attempt: Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the union of the $\sigma$-algebras generated by
$\mathcal{F}$ as $\mathcal{F}$ ranges over all countable subsets of
$\mathcal{E}$. I *can* prove that $\mathcal{N}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

> But how do I prove that $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$?

If $\mathcal{E}$ is countable, then it is clear. But what happens if $\mathcal{E}$ is uncountable? I appreciate any help.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292017/generated-sigma-algebra-from-countable-sub-familys-of-a-collection-of-subsets).

Comment: This is probably $\mathcal E\subseteq2^X$, not $\mathcal E\subseteq X$.

Comment: @Did: Corrected :-)

Comment: Actually, $\mathcal E\in2^X$ and $\mathcal E\subseteq X$ are equivalent hence $\mathcal E\in2^X$ is wrong as well.

Comment: @Did: Ahhh I am blind

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thanks Michael. Your answer was useful to me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $E\in\mathcal{E}$.

Then $\mathcal{F}=\left\{ E\right\} $ is
a countable subset of $\mathcal{E}$ and $E$ is contained in the
$\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}$.

Then also $E\in\mathcal{N}$ (the union).

Proved is now that $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$

Comment: So simple! Thank you very much. I was confusing the subsets of $X$ and subsets of $2^{X}$...

Answer (score 6):

Here's a complete proof for the reference. Taken from [here.](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~roberlin/maa5616.f13/homework1sln.pdf) I am making this post community-wiki.

[image]

Comment: There is a typo in the beginning of third paragraph. It should say "To see that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ we first notice that…" I will correct it when I get the chance to latexify the post (right now, it's only a screenshot)